# Aggregating hourly location data into daily sublocation data for many columns

Tags: vba, excel, hash-map

I start with an hourly table that has around 40 of items (example: bread, barley, bagels, beef, chicken). The purpose of my code is to aggregate this hourly table's numbers to daily numbers but broken out by a sublocation or "type". My only way to allocate to type is to use a table that shows the % breakdown of type to location. This table, however, is at the Monthly day/night (Timeframe) granularity. I solved the problem with a dictionary for each item, but extending this out makes me believe I am doing this inefficiently.

I could use some opinions on how to better organize my code to handle dozens of items. A forewarning that I have never used collections or classes out of ignorance, but I am open to anything.

*note: I converted these tables in markdown format using this [site](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)

**Hourly Table Example** (~700,000 rows, ~40 columns to aggregate) <Pasted into **B5**>

| Day | Location | Hour | Timeframe | bread | barley | bagels | beef | chicken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/1/2021 | A | 0 | night | 51 | 91 | 12 | 26 | 176 |
| 4/1/2021 | A | 1 | night | 51 | 24 | 4 | 43 | 17 |
| 4/1/2021 | A | 8 | day | 25 | 84 | 5 | 72 | 125 |
| 4/1/2021 | A | 14 | day | 32 | 10 | 7 | 7 | 166 |
| 4/2/2021 | A | 0 | night | 31 | 29 | 11 | 49 | 5 |
| 4/2/2021 | A | 1 | night | 25 | 25 | 3 | 40 | 175 |
| 4/2/2021 | A | 8 | day | 70 | 81 | 6 | 69 | 89 |
| 4/2/2021 | A | 14 | day | 83 | 45 | 2 | 9 | 141 |
| 4/1/2021 | B | 0 | night | 55 | 37 | 8 | 59 | 164 |
| 4/1/2021 | B | 1 | night | 53 | 88 | 12 | 50 | 74 |
| 4/1/2021 | B | 8 | day | 20 | 73 | 1 | 33 | 200 |
| 4/1/2021 | B | 14 | day | 6 | 33 | 7 | 2 | 191 |
| 4/2/2021 | B | 0 | night | 39 | 52 | 4 | 22 | 99 |
| 4/2/2021 | B | 1 | night | 19 | 80 | 6 | 55 | 0 |
| 4/2/2021 | B | 8 | day | 44 | 49 | 10 | 42 | 8 |
| 4/2/2021 | B | 14 | day | 72 | 11 | 3 | 54 | 44 |

Here is a Monthly table that will be used to breakout daily numbers. There relationship between item-to-multiplier is one-to-many so in this example, bread, barley, and bagels are broken out by multiplier1, while beef and chicken are broken out by multiplier2. These breakouts are actually at the timeframe level so must occur before the day has been aggregated.

**BREAKOUT TABLE** Monthly Location with % of total listed by Type+Timeframe <Pasted in **L5**>

| Month | Location | type | Timeframe | Multiplier1 | Multiplier2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/1/2021 | A | x | day | 16% | 8% |
| 4/1/2021 | A | y | day | 84% | 92% |
| 4/1/2021 | A | x | night | 33% | 25% |
| 4/1/2021 | A | y | night | 67% | 75% |
| 4/1/2021 | B | x | day | 50% | 42% |
| 4/1/2021 | B | y | day | 50% | 58% |
| 4/1/2021 | B | x | night | 100% | 92% |
| 4/1/2021 | B | y | night | 0% | 8% |
| 5/1/2021 | A | x | day | 26% | 17% |
| 5/1/2021 | A | y | day | 74% | 83% |
| 5/1/2021 | A | x | night | 51% | 43% |
| 5/1/2021 | A | y | night | 49% | 57% |
| 5/1/2021 | B | x | day | 1% | 4% |
| 5/1/2021 | B | y | day | 99% | 96% |
| 5/1/2021 | B | x | night | 2% | 5% |
| 5/1/2021 | B | y | night | 98% | 95% |

Here is the resulting intended table:

**DAILY TABLE** Day+Location+Type <Pasted in **S5**>

| Day | Location | type | bread | barley | bagels | beef | chicken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/1/2021 | A | x | 42.78 | 52.99 | 7.2 | 23.57 | 71.53 |
| 4/2/2021 | A | x | 42.96 | 37.98 | 5.9 | 28.49 | 63.4 |
| 4/1/2021 | B | x | 121 | 178 | 24 | 114.98 | 383.18 |
| 4/2/2021 | B | x | 116 | 162 | 16.5 | 111.16 | 112.92 |
| 4/1/2021 | A | y | 116.22 | 156.01 | 20.8 | 124.43 | 412.47 |
| 4/2/2021 | A | y | 166.04 | 142.02 | 16.1 | 138.51 | 346.6 |
| 4/1/2021 | B | y | 13 | 53 | 4 | 29.02 | 245.82 |
| 4/2/2021 | B | y | 58 | 30 | 6.5 | 61.84 | 38.08 |

And here is my current working code. Please let me know your thoughts and spare no criticism (I know I'm naming variables inconsistently).

```
Sub hourly_timeframe_to_day_type()
    ' Aggregate a table at the hourly+location+timeframe level
    ' to the daily+location+type level
    
    ' requires "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference enabled (Tools>References) to scripting.dictionary objects
    
    '-----------------------------------------------------
    ' Save the table with multipliers and save column header references
    '-----------------------------------------------------
    Dim breakout_array As Variant: breakout_array = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("L5").CurrentRegion
    With Application
        Dim breakout_month_col As Long: breakout_month_col = .Match("Month", .Index(breakout_array, 1, 0), 0)
        Dim breakout_location_col As Long: breakout_location_col = .Match("Location", .Index(breakout_array, 1, 0), 0)
        Dim breakout_type_col As Long: breakout_type_col = .Match("type", .Index(breakout_array, 1, 0), 0)
        Dim breakout_timeframe_col As Long: breakout_timeframe_col = .Match("Timeframe", .Index(breakout_array, 1, 0), 0)
        Dim breakout_multiplier1_col As Long: breakout_multiplier1_col = .Match("Multiplier1", .Index(breakout_array, 1, 0), 0)
        Dim breakout_multiplier2_col As Long: breakout_multiplier2_col = .Match("Multiplier2", .Index(breakout_array, 1, 0), 0)
    End With

    '-----------------------------------------------------
    ' Create dictionaries to track the multiplier using the column references
    '-----------------------------------------------------
    Dim MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier2_dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier2_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim types As Scripting.Dictionary: Set types = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(breakout_array, 1)
        ' Month + Location + Type + Timeframe
        ' 4/1/2021 + A + x + day
        multiplierkeystring = _
            breakout_array(i, breakout_month_col) & _
            breakout_array(i, breakout_location_col) & _
            breakout_array(i, breakout_type_col) & _
            breakout_array(i, breakout_timeframe_col)
            
        MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict(multiplierkeystring) = breakout_array(i, breakout_multiplier1_col)
        MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier2_dict(multiplierkeystring) = breakout_array(i, breakout_multiplier2_col)
        ' list of possible types
        types(breakout_array(i, breakout_type_col)) = 1
    Next i

    Dim hrly_array As Variant: hrly_array = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B5").CurrentRegion
    With Application
        'Dim hrly_month_col As Long: hrly_month_col = .Match("Month", .Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)
        Dim hrly_location_col As Long: hrly_location_col = .Match("Location", .Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)
        Dim hrly_timeframe_col As Long: hrly_timeframe_col = .Match("Timeframe", .Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)
        Dim hrly_day_col As Long: hrly_day_col = .Match("Day", .Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)
        
        Dim hrly_bread_col As Long: hrly_bread_col = .Match("bread", .Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)
        Dim hrly_barley_col As Long: hrly_barley_col = .Match("barley", .Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)
        Dim hrly_bagels_col As Long: hrly_bagels_col = .Match("bagels", .Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)
        Dim hrly_beef_col As Long: hrly_beef_col = .Match("beef", .Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)
        Dim hrly_chicken_col As Long: hrly_chicken_col = .Match("chicken", .Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)
        ' ~40 more items
    End With

    Dim DayLocationType_bread_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set DayLocationType_bread_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim DayLocationType_barley_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set DayLocationType_barley_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim DayLocationType_bagels_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set DayLocationType_bagels_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim DayLocationType_beef_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set DayLocationType_beef_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim DayLocationType_chicken_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set DayLocationType_chicken_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ' ~40 more items
    
    ' the first few columns
    Dim day_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set day_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim location_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set location_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim type_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set type_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    '-----------------------------------------------------
    ' Turn the hourly into daily type
    '-----------------------------------------------------
    Dim dailykeystring As String
    Dim possible_type As Variant
    
    For Each possible_type In types
        For i = 2 To UBound(hrly_array, 1) ' could be 700,000 rows
            ' define key strings

            multiplierkeystring = _
                DateSerial(Year(hrly_array(i, hrly_day_col)), Month(hrly_array(i, hrly_day_col)), 1) & _
                hrly_array(i, hrly_location_col) & _
                possible_type & _
                hrly_array(i, hrly_timeframe_col)

            dailykeystring = hrly_array(i, hrly_day_col) & hrly_array(i, hrly_location_col) & possible_type
            
            
            ' if this combination exists then continue
            ' and only need to check one dictionary since they all share the same key
            '-------------------------
            If MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict.Exists(multiplierkeystring) Then
            
                '-------------------------
                ' Headers
                '-------------------------
                day_dict(dailykeystring) = hrly_array(i, hrly_day_col)
                location_dict(dailykeystring) = hrly_array(i, hrly_location_col)
                type_dict(dailykeystring) = possible_type

                '--------------------------------------------------
                ' Hourly+Location+Timeframe to Day+Location+Type
                '--------------------------------------------------
                
                If Not DayLocationType_bread_dict.Exists(dailykeystring) Then
                    '------------------------------------------
                    ' Start Aggregating
                    '------------------------------------------
                    
                    ' Multipier1
                    '-------------------------
                    DayLocationType_bread_dict(dailykeystring) = hrly_array(i, hrly_bread_col) _
                        * MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict(multiplierkeystring)
                        
                    DayLocationType_barley_dict(dailykeystring) = hrly_array(i, hrly_barley_col) _
                        * MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict(multiplierkeystring)
                        
                    DayLocationType_bagels_dict(dailykeystring) = hrly_array(i, hrly_bagels_col) _
                        * MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict(multiplierkeystring)
                    
                    ' Multipier2
                    '-------------------------
                    DayLocationType_beef_dict(dailykeystring) = hrly_array(i, hrly_beef_col) _
                        * MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier2_dict(multiplierkeystring)
                    
                    DayLocationType_chicken_dict(dailykeystring) = hrly_array(i, hrly_chicken_col) _
                        * MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier2_dict(multiplierkeystring)
                        
                    ' ~40 more items
                Else
                    '------------------------------------------
                    ' Continue Aggregate
                    '------------------------------------------
                    
                    ' Multiplier1
                    '-------------------------
                    DayLocationType_bread_dict(dailykeystring) = DayLocationType_bread_dict(dailykeystring) _
                        + hrly_array(i, hrly_bread_col) * MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict(multiplierkeystring)
                        
                    DayLocationType_barley_dict(dailykeystring) = DayLocationType_barley_dict(dailykeystring) _
                        + hrly_array(i, hrly_barley_col) * MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict(multiplierkeystring)

                    DayLocationType_bagels_dict(dailykeystring) = DayLocationType_bagels_dict(dailykeystring) _
                        + hrly_array(i, hrly_bagels_col) * MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict(multiplierkeystring)
                    
                    ' Multiplier2
                    '-------------------------
                    DayLocationType_beef_dict(dailykeystring) = DayLocationType_beef_dict(dailykeystring) _
                        + hrly_array(i, hrly_beef_col) * MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier2_dict(multiplierkeystring)
                        
                    DayLocationType_chicken_dict(dailykeystring) = DayLocationType_chicken_dict(dailykeystring) _
                        + hrly_array(i, hrly_chicken_col) * MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier2_dict(multiplierkeystring)
                        
                    ' ~40 more items
                End If
                
            End If
        Next i
    Next possible_type

    '-----------------------------------------------------
    ' Print the Results
    '-----------------------------------------------------
    Dim daily_rows As Long: daily_rows = DayLocationType_bread_dict.Count
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("AC6")
    
        ' headers
        '-------------------------
        .Offset(0, 0).Resize(daily_rows, 1) = Application.Transpose(day_dict.Items)
        .Offset(0, 1).Resize(daily_rows, 1) = Application.Transpose(location_dict.Items)
        .Offset(0, 2).Resize(daily_rows, 1) = Application.Transpose(type_dict.Items)
        
        ' items
        '-------------------------
        .Offset(0, 3).Resize(daily_rows, 1) = Application.Transpose(DayLocationType_bread_dict.Items)
        .Offset(0, 4).Resize(daily_rows, 1) = Application.Transpose(DayLocationType_barley_dict.Items)
        .Offset(0, 5).Resize(daily_rows, 1) = Application.Transpose(DayLocationType_bagels_dict.Items)
        .Offset(0, 6).Resize(daily_rows, 1) = Application.Transpose(DayLocationType_beef_dict.Items)
        .Offset(0, 7).Resize(daily_rows, 1) = Application.Transpose(DayLocationType_chicken_dict.Items)
        
        ' ~40 more items
        '-------------------------
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Would you be open to suggestions about non-vba alternatives? For example, have you used pivot tables before - is there a reason you didn't use them for the aggregation? My initial thought would be to add some lookup columns to grab data from table 2 and put it in table 1, then use a pivot table on table 1 to aggregate it. Alternatively, powerquery would be a good tool for transforming and joining the two tables, have you come across this before? I generally avoid VBA for big data crunching as I think Excel has all the tools built in, and PQ is there for SQL levels of speed.

Comment: Hi Greedo, thanks for the edit and the ideas. I use both but less often in my automated work. This is an end-step in a large process and I’m not sure how much legible and efficient either option would be in the rest of my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a class to hold the data specific to the various items will help eliminate a lot of *nearly* duplicated code in your subroutine.  The approach is that you define a class to hold data and objects relevant and unique to each item (bread, barely,chicken, etc). Doing so allows you to operate using loops.

So, a class like (TableItem) below:

```
    Option Explicit

    Private mBreakoutTableColumn As Long
    Private mResultOffsetColumn As Long
    Private mItemName As String
    Private mMultipliers As Dictionary
    Private myDict As Dictionary

    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        Set myDict = New Dictionary
    End Sub

    Public Property Get DailyRowCount() As Long
        DailyRowCount = myDict.Count
    End Property

    Public Property Get ItemName() As String
        ItemName = mItemName
    End Property
    Public Property Let ItemName(ByVal RHS As String)
        mItemName = RHS
    End Property

    Public Property Get BreakoutTableColumn() As Long
        BreakoutTableColumn = mBreakoutTableColumn
    End Property

    Public Property Let BreakoutTableColumn(ByVal RHS As Long)
        mBreakoutTableColumn = RHS
    End Property

    Public Property Get ResultOffsetColumn() As Long
        ResultOffsetColumn = mResultOffsetColumn
    End Property

    Public Sub LoadUniqueContent(ByVal identifier As String, ByVal colNumber As Long, ByVal multipliers As Dictionary, ByVal rsltOffsetColumn As Long)
        ItemName = identifier
        BreakoutTableColumn = colNumber
        mResultOffsetColumn = rsltOffsetColumn
        Set mMultipliers = multipliers
    End Sub

    Public Function MultiplierKeyExists(ByVal multiplierKey As String) As Boolean
        MultiplierKeyExists = mMultipliers.Exists(multiplierKey)
    End Function

    Public Sub Aggregate(ByRef dailykeystring As String, ByRef multiplierkeystring As String, ByVal valToAggregate As Double)
        If Not myDict.Exists(dailykeystring) Then
            myDict(dailykeystring) = valToAggregate _
                * mMultipliers(multiplierkeystring)
        Else
            myDict(dailykeystring) = myDict(dailykeystring) + valToAggregate _
                * mMultipliers(multiplierkeystring)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function TransposeItem() As Variant
        TransposeItem = Application.Transpose(myDict.Items)
    End Function
```

Makes using loops possible. (Changes start about the middle of the subroutine)

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub hourly_timeframe_to_day_type()
        ' Aggregate a table at the hourly+location+timeframe level
        ' to the daily+location+type level
        
        ' requires "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference enabled (Tools>References) to scripting.dictionary objects
        
        '-----------------------------------------------------
        ' Save the table with multipliers and save column header references
        '-----------------------------------------------------
        
        'Dim breakout_array As Variant: breakout_array = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakout").Range("L5").CurrentRegion
        Dim breakout_array As Variant: breakout_array = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Breakout").Range("A1:F17")
        With Application
            Dim breakout_month_col As Long: breakout_month_col = .Match("Month", .Index(breakout_array, 1, 0), 0)
            Dim breakout_location_col As Long: breakout_location_col = .Match("Location", .Index(breakout_array, 1, 0), 0)
            Dim breakout_type_col As Long: breakout_type_col = .Match("type", .Index(breakout_array, 1, 0), 0)
            Dim breakout_timeframe_col As Long: breakout_timeframe_col = .Match("Timeframe", .Index(breakout_array, 1, 0), 0)
            Dim breakout_multiplier1_col As Long: breakout_multiplier1_col = .Match("Multiplier1", .Index(breakout_array, 1, 0), 0)
            Dim breakout_multiplier2_col As Long: breakout_multiplier2_col = .Match("Multiplier2", .Index(breakout_array, 1, 0), 0)
        End With

        '-----------------------------------------------------
        ' Create dictionaries to track the multiplier using the column references
        '-----------------------------------------------------
        Dim MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        Dim MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier2_dict As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier2_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        Dim types As Scripting.Dictionary: Set types = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        Dim multiplierkeystring As String
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To UBound(breakout_array, 1)
            ' Month + Location + Type + Timeframe
            ' 4/1/2021 + A + x + day
            multiplierkeystring = _
                breakout_array(i, breakout_month_col) & _
                breakout_array(i, breakout_location_col) & _
                breakout_array(i, breakout_type_col) & _
                breakout_array(i, breakout_timeframe_col)
                
            MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict(multiplierkeystring) = breakout_array(i, breakout_multiplier1_col)
            MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier2_dict(multiplierkeystring) = breakout_array(i, breakout_multiplier2_col)
            ' list of possible types
            types(breakout_array(i, breakout_type_col)) = 1
        Next i
        
        
    '*******************************CHANGES START HERE**********************************

        'Load items into a collection
        Dim tblItems As Collection
        Set tblItems = New Collection
        
        'Dim hrly_array As Variant: hrly_array = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B5").CurrentRegion
        Dim hrly_array As Variant: hrly_array = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Hourly").Range("A1:I17")
        With Application
            Dim hrly_location_col As Long: hrly_location_col = .Match("Location", .Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)
            Dim hrly_timeframe_col As Long: hrly_timeframe_col = .Match("Timeframe", .Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)
            Dim hrly_day_col As Long: hrly_day_col = .Match("Day", .Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)
        End With
            
        'defaultTableItem is used for extracting data common to all items without having to access the collection
        Dim defaultTableItem As TableItem
        Set defaultTableItem = CreateTableItem("bread", hrly_array, MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict, 3)
        tblItems.Add defaultTableItem
        
        Dim tblItem As TableItem
        Set tblItem = CreateTableItem("barley", hrly_array, MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict, 4)
        tblItems.Add tblItem
        
        Set tblItem = CreateTableItem("bagels", hrly_array, MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier1_dict, 5)
        tblItems.Add tblItem
        
        Set tblItem = CreateTableItem("beef", hrly_array, MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier2_dict, 6)
        tblItems.Add tblItem
        
        Set tblItem = CreateTableItem("chicken", hrly_array, MonthLocationTimeframeType_Multiplier2_dict, 7)
        tblItems.Add tblItem
        ' ~40 more items
        

        'Dim DayLocationType_bread_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set DayLocationType_bread_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        'Dim DayLocationType_barley_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set DayLocationType_barley_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        'Dim DayLocationType_bagels_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set DayLocationType_bagels_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        'Dim DayLocationType_beef_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set DayLocationType_beef_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        'Dim DayLocationType_chicken_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set DayLocationType_chicken_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        ' ~40 more items REMOVED
        
        ' the first few columns
        Dim day_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set day_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim location_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set location_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        Dim type_dict As Scripting.Dictionary: Set type_dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
        '-----------------------------------------------------
        ' Turn the hourly into daily type
        '-----------------------------------------------------
        Dim dailykeystring As String
        Dim possible_type As Variant
        
        For Each possible_type In types
            For i = 2 To UBound(hrly_array, 1) ' could be 700,000 rows
                ' define key strings

                multiplierkeystring = _
                    DateSerial(Year(hrly_array(i, hrly_day_col)), Month(hrly_array(i, hrly_day_col)), 1) & _
                    hrly_array(i, hrly_location_col) & _
                    possible_type & _
                    hrly_array(i, hrly_timeframe_col)

                dailykeystring = hrly_array(i, hrly_day_col) & hrly_array(i, hrly_location_col) & possible_type
                
                Aggregate tblItems, dailykeystring, multiplierkeystring, hrly_array, i
                '~40+ lines REMOVED
                
                ' if this combination exists then continue
                ' and only need to check one dictionary since they all share the same key
                '-------------------------
                If defaultTableItem.MultiplierKeyExists(multiplierkeystring) Then
                
                    '-------------------------
                    ' Headers
                    '-------------------------
                    day_dict(dailykeystring) = hrly_array(i, hrly_day_col)
                    location_dict(dailykeystring) = hrly_array(i, hrly_location_col)
                    type_dict(dailykeystring) = possible_type
                    
                End If
            Next i
        Next possible_type

        '-----------------------------------------------------
        ' Print the Results
        '-----------------------------------------------------
        Dim daily_rows As Long
        daily_rows = defaultTableItem.DailyRowCount
        
        'With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("AC6")
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily").Range("A1")
        
            ' headers
            '-------------------------
            .Offset(0, 0).Resize(daily_rows, 1) = Application.Transpose(day_dict.Items)
            .Offset(0, 1).Resize(daily_rows, 1) = Application.Transpose(location_dict.Items)
            .Offset(0, 2).Resize(daily_rows, 1) = Application.Transpose(type_dict.Items)
            
            ' items ~40+ lines removed
            '-------------------------
            Dim tblItm As Variant
            For Each tblItm In tblItems
                Set tblItem = tblItm
                .Offset(0, tblItem.ResultOffsetColumn).Resize(daily_rows, 1) = tblItem.TransposeItem()
            Next
        End With
        
    End Sub
    Private Sub Aggregate(ByVal itemsCollection As Collection, ByVal dailykeystring As String, ByVal multiplierkeystring As String, ByRef hrlyArray As Variant, ByVal idx As Long)
        
        Dim tblItem As TableItem
        Dim itm As Variant
        For Each itm In itemsCollection
            Set tblItem = itm
            tblItem.Aggregate dailykeystring, multiplierkeystring, hrlyArray(idx, tblItem.BreakoutTableColumn)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function CreateTableItem(ByVal identifier As String, ByRef hrly_array As Variant, ByVal multipliers As Dictionary, ByVal rsltOffsetColumn As Long) As TableItem
        Dim tblItem As TableItem
        Set tblItem = New TableItem
        Dim breakoutCol As Long
        breakoutCol = Application.Match(identifier, Application.Index(hrly_array, 1, 0), 0)

        tblItem.LoadUniqueContent identifier, breakoutCol, multipliers, rsltOffsetColumn
        Set CreateTableItem = tblItem
    End Function
```

As you can see, the 40+ lines to configure each class instance are still needed.  Once that is done, the code can operate on the `Collection` generically.